# go - Load image using Gin

Tags: go

I develop web application, But I can't load image. `.css` and `.js` file can be loaded by `Static()` method. Image is also same? How to load Image to web application using Gin?

```
router.Static("/css", "./css") // this is loading css file
router.Static("/js", "./js") // this is loading js file
// How to load Image?
```

Comment: You can do that check the answer.Your path might be wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use `StaticFile` to serve a single file

```
router.StaticFile("/favicon.ico", "./resources/favicon.ico")
```

If you want to serve static image given its path,you may use it just like js and css

```
router.Static("/img", "./img")
```

or

```
import "github.com/gin-gonic/contrib/static"
.
.
.
router.Use(static.Serve("/img", static.LocalFile("./img", true)))
```